# Windows 8, Wrong GPU detection

Tags: windows-8, drivers, gpu, amd-radeon

I have a HP DV6 laptop with ATI Radeon HD 6490M GPU. It came with Windows 7 preinstalled. I recently installed Windows 8 Pro onto it. The GPU(s) shown are Intel HD 3000 and **ATI Radeon HD 7400 Series**

How is this possible, Windows 8 detects a wrong GPU and installs the Driver also. The GPU shows a warning sign (error). I am not able to use the GPU, catalyst also doesn't recognize this GPU.

The GPU works perfect on Windows 7. I tried installing Win 7 drivers but it doesn't help much, the correct GPU is detected but it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Also I feel like no Windows 8 64bit Driver is available for this GPU.

Answer (score 1):

[HP provides a guide](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video-e-g-Windows-8/I-upgraded-to-Windows-8-How-do-I-get-switchable-graphics-to/m-p/2213275#M59120) how to enable the GPU:

> 1. Install the HP Software Framework as found [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-110992-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5317866&sw_lang=).
> 2. Next, uninstall all ATI/AMD software through Programs and Features.
> 3. Go to www.hp.com and select Support and Drivers at the top.
> 4. Select Software and Driver downloads and enter your product model or product number.
> 5. Select the most recent operating system matching your installation of Windows 8's bit architecture.  For example, Windows 7 64bit for
>      Windows 8 64bit.
> 6. Download the ATI graphics card driver.
> 7. Run the file once it is finished downloading.
> 8. Let the extraction process finish, but cancel the installation when prompted to continue it after the extraction.  Take note of where
>      this is extracted to.  By default, this should be
>      c:\swsetup\.
> 9. Here, there should be a setup.exe for installing the ATI driver.  Right-click this and select troubleshoot compatibility.
> 10. Follow the compatibility troulbeshooter and select the suggested fixes.  On one screen, there will be a test program button.  Click
>       this to begin the installation.
> 11. Follow the installation and it should finish successfully.
> 12. Once finished, right-click the desktop to verify the configure switchable graphics option is listed.

Try it, maybe it works for you, too.

Comment: Sorry, I dint update you. This dint work for me, unfortunately.