# Enabling AMD Catalyst Driver in Windows 8 causes Laptop display to be turned off

Tags: windows-8, ati-mobility-radeon, hp-envy

I have a 2010 HP Envy 14 which has a hybrid Intel HD IGP/ AMD 5650 Discrete GPU running on Windows 8.

Off late, my laptop has had problems overheating, which was a result of the system fan not working. During the process of "verifying" that the system fan was not working, my Windows 8 install crashed bad and I had to do a fresh install of Windows 8, bringing it to a clean slate state.

Post the Windows install, I proceeded to install [AMD Catalyst 12.11 beta drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx)(since HP's official's drivers aren't and will never be updated) and I noticed that midway during the install, the laptop display was switched off. After waiting for 5 minutes, I rebooted my system, only to find the same result - the laptop display simply won't turn on.

If I put the laptop to sleep and then wake it up, the display is turned on momentarily, and then it gets switched off. From this, I deduced that the moment AMD drivers are enabled, the display gets turned off. To confirm: I booted into safe mode, disabled the 5650 drivers, rebooted back to normal and the laptop display is perfectly fine. The moment I enable the AMD 5650 drivers, the laptop display gets switched off.

Why is this display getting turned off post the fresh install? I don't believe the beta drivers aren't to blame since the same set of display drivers worked perfectly prior to the fresh install.

I should mention that while the initial Windows 8 install was broken I was running on Linux Mint for a bit and was playing around with [VGA switcheroo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics), trying to get it working. Without the AMD drivers, there's no way I can get the HDMI out working and I need the HDMI out since I have a multiple-display extended desktop system.

Has VGA switcheroo caused the discrete display to be turned off?

Comment: Since I installed the AMD drivers on my Dell laptop I have a two minute wait after the machine comes out of sleep before I get anything on screen. It's painful. How long did you wait?

Comment: @Brannon the system comes out of sleep fairly instantly, about 10 seconds or so - I can see the display then. It's after that, when the AMD driver is enabled that the display goes off

Comment: try the steps I've posted yesterday: http://superuser.com/questions/523298/windows-8-wrong-gpu-detection/523388#523388

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks, but that doesn't work because the Win 7 drivers are older than the ones come with Win 8, so the drivers don't get installed

Comment: that why it mentions the compatibility in step 9.

Comment: @magicandre1981 compatibility doesn't force Windows to install drivers older than the ones already present.

Comment: you can use pnputil to kill all installed AMD GPU drivers. Now it should work.

Comment: have you removed the newer driver? does the older driver works?

Comment: @magicandre1981 it didn't. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After day long of forced reboots, and troubleshooting, I *think* I've managed to get this working.

I had to disable Microsoft's Intel HD Drivers. The thing was when the AMD drivers were activated, the display was routed via the AMD Drivers but the Intel driver route was still set as 'default', preventing the display being shown.

The extended desktop setup now works fine

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue for myself also on an Envy14 with AMD and Intel HD.   Even with latest of both drivers, on W7, it was doing the same and turning off the display, even with all sleep settings.
After i disabled. Intel HD all is good!

Comment: so disabling intel hd is a solution?could u breif it a little?