# Windows 8 fails to switch to dedicated graphics chip in HP Laptop

Tags: windows, 64-bit, temperature

I just installed windows 8 pro and i experience really high tempratures.

I have an hp laptop with hybrid graphics (ati/intel) and my laptop has 65°-70° idle...I cleaned if from dust 3 months ago and in windows 7 i had 40°-45° idle before installing windows 8 pro, so something is wrong..Intel graphics driver is fine but ati 5000 series is not starting...Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing the issue?

Comment: You say the dedicated graphics card isn't starting - I'm not sure I'm following the connection between there and high temperatures. Do you have a monitoring tool reporting excessive temperatures on the GPU sensors, or an error message to that effect? Also, can you include the model of laptop you're working with?

Comment: i am running coretemp all day long and the temprature is what i mentioned..if i do something "harder" my laptop turns off..I mentioned graphics caused i saw on some forums that this usually happens on users with intel graphics, but i can't see why either..

Comment: Is the laptop sitting on a flat surface and getting good ventilation and cool air? Is the CPU fan spinning and moving air through the system? Have you checked it for dust again? This sounds like a general system cooling problem, not specific to the GPU if stressing the CPU will also cause that to overheat.

Comment: the laptop is not sitting on flat surface, i have some books raising it and the cooling system works excellant that way...As i said, one week ago with windows 7, i had 45 degrees so i guess, the cpu fan is running fine.

Comment: Which set of drivers are you using? You might need AMD's beta drivers and might need to disable Intel's IGP. See [Enabling AMD Catalyst Driver in Windows 8 causes Laptop display to be turned off](http://superuser.com/q/523605)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear.

You installed Win8 Pro on your [unknown model] HP laptop, and you downloaded all the Windows 8 drivers from HP for your model laptop... especially the video drivers... and you installed them, and they all installed without an issue.  After all that, the IGP doesn't work while in Windows?

Or, did you just download the video drivers for whatever the non-IGP chip is in your laptop, and installed those?  Or, did you download both sets of drivers independently for both chips, install them both, and then expect it to switch based on demand?

Unfortunately, laptops that use dual video chipsets in this type of configuration have drivers made by the laptop manufacturer that are designed to work with the hardware as they have it set up in the laptop.  The Windows 7 video drivers might work... and they might not.  But if HP doesn't support Windows 8 on your model laptop, meaning if they don't have any Windows 8 drivers available for download, you might be out of luck as far as installing Windows 8 goes.

Hard to say without knowing the model laptop that you have.  You know... hard to recommend what to download and all that.

Comment: You are right, i have a g62 laptop(the model was in the question which has been edited) and hp site has no drivers for windows 8..Intel graphics drivers work fine but the drivers for ati dont. I have't tried choosing windows 7 drivers but ati drivers for 5000x are designed for both windows 7 and 8, so i guessed there would be no difference.